# Performance of VS 2005 compare to VC++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++

How to improve the performance of VS 2005 VC++ compare to VC++ 6.0??
Examaple by setting compiler flags...
any other listing which will improve the performance of VS 2005

Comment: are you referring to the speed of the IDE or the programs it produces?

Comment: IDE as well as in coding wise...eg.STL,...

Answer (score 2):

As far as the speed of the IDE goes, upgrading to VS2008 made a noticeable improvement for me.  Of course better hardware (especially more memory) will also help.

But I doubt you'll ever get the same performance as VS6 - it was much smaller environment (in terms of memory use) and was entirely native code.

As far as the speed of what you build - as long as you're comparing apples to apples (native code release builds and comparable functionality), what you build with VS2005 should not be slower than what you build with VS6.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much you can do to make Visual Studio feel as responsive as 6.0 except upgrade your hardware. Visual Studio 2005 was made for newer hardware and released in 2005, while 6.0 was released in 1998. It's a small price to pay for the dramatic improvements in the software.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about C++/CLI/.NET or Just plain old C++? There's a BIG difference. If your using .NET you'll notice a major performance hit. This is due to the fact that you are running your code on a VM, whereas C++ is native code.

Comment: Then I guess your talking about the IDE only?

Comment: IDE as well as codingwise..eg: STLs , any other settings,